# UIImagePicker on full screen on iPad

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

For my tests, I need to create a simple app on the iPad to
  step 1. loads an image from the Photo library (UIImagePickerController).
  step 2. Then, this image is converted into texture and displayed into an OpenGL ES view.

I started to define the app with the XCode Open GL ES template.
Step 2 is Okay.
But I have a problem launching the UIImagePickerController (step 1).

On iPad, to create a UIImagePickerController, we need to use a UIPopoverController.
But to create a UIPopover, we need to attach it to a content view controller

In my app, I dont want to define a specific view controller (Navigation or SplitView or TabBar...). I just need to have the UIImagePicker displayed on full screen when launching the app.

I am looking for a programatical solution with a minimum of lines of code added from the Open GL ES iPad template, to perform step 1 (step 2 is okay for me).

any code available?
Thank you for your help
Seb

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same exact problem as you and I am thinking that accessing the Camera Roll might be purposefully blocked by Apple as they specifically mention opening up access to the Camera Roll in version 4.0 of iPhoneOS while the current consumer iPad/Phone OS is 3.2.  4.0 will become available to us in the summer for the iPhone but I haven't heard of the same being true for the iPad.  I sure hope so though.  Feel free to drop me a line if you figure this one out :-)  Thanks and good luck bud!

Rene Vogt-Lowell
rene@vogt-lowell.com
http://CreatorsInk.com